# Can I re-render only part of a table in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, lazy-loading, intersection-observer

I want to display a long (2000+ rows) table with images in vue.js

Currently I manage to lazy-load the rows and images using the [IntersectionObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), which adds more rows and the corresponding images as the user scrolls.

However that means that all the rows are re-rendered every time, which makes for a choppy experience as the table gets longer.

Is there a way to make the first x rows "sticky" (i.e.: no re-render) and only add and render the next batch?

Comment: Do you mean v-once ?

Comment: @EstusFlask - yes, now that I know it exists, it looks like that could be a solution. Googling a bit seems to say it has problems inside v-for, but let me try it first

Comment: Sounds like you need to paginate your data